# mysql - insert into select with lat/lng to POINT column? 40k rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `lookup` that has zip, city, state, latitude, longitude columns (about 40k rows).  What I want to do is copy the data into a new table named `lookup2`, BUT rather than having latitude and longitude columns in this table I have a single column named `position` of type POINT.

This is not valid of course, but you should get the idea of what I am trying to achieve here :

```
INSERT INTO lookup2 (zip, city, state, position)
SELECT zip, city, state, PointFromText(POINT(longitude latitude)) FROM lookup;
```

Is something like this possible for INSERT INTO SELECT?  How can I 'convert' this lookup table into the new format on the other table?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - there is probably another way to do this other than using CONCAT, but this worked like a charm for me and using ST_X(position) and ST_Y(position) on the new table is returning the correct lng/lat values per zip or whatever lookup I am using.

```
INSERT INTO lookup2 (zip, city, state, position)
SELECT zip, city, state, PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT (', longitude, ' ', latitude, ')')) as position FROM lookup
```